# Use matplotlib on Raspbberrypi

Tags: pi-2, python-3

Using The following Code for saving plot locally on raspberry:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import plotly.io as pio
y = range(10)
x = range(10)
plt.title("Adc data") 
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('foo.png',edgecolor='RED',transparent=True)
```

'Raspberry pi has Jessie lite' 
the Error is

`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:10.0"`

Is there any other way to save the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server

Comment: This is really a straight Python question better suited to (and already answered on - see link above) Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib in the configuration as shown in your code tries to output its graph to the screen. That fails horribly since Jessie lite comes without the X server. No GUI, no Matplotlib rendering output.

> ... saving plot locally

If you're not interrested in directly showing the graph via Matplotlib but want to save that plot to a file instead one can use the AGG backend is for writing to file, not for rendering in a window. Important line is `matplotlib.use('Agg')`. It should look like this:

```
import matplotlib
# IMPORTANT to export figures w/o x-server
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.savefig('foo.png',edgecolor='RED',transparent=True)
```

---

From [matplotlib's FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html):

> There are two types of backends: user interface backends (for use in pygtk, wxpython, tkinter, qt4, or macosx; also referred to as “interactive backends”) and hardcopy backends to make image files (PNG, SVG, PDF, PS; also referred to as “non-interactive backends”).
>
> [...]
>
> Here is a summary of the matplotlib renderers (there is an eponymous backed for each; these are non-interactive backends, capable of writing to a file):

[image]
<sub><sup>[Image source](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Hey Thanks, But can you tell me how it works?

Comment: @RiturajRautela; I don't understand. The problem as stated in your question is that you're trying to use the default "interactive backend" which then tries to render its output on screen which in turn fails as there is no X server running. Selecting "AGG" as a non-interactive backend prevents this.

Comment: Hey, Now there is some problem with creating graphs. The function is plotting multiple graphs on the next file as I continue to make new png's.

Comment: @RiturajRautela after saving the file and before plotting new stuff you likely want to invoke [`plt.clf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228808/3984613).